# Best practice for Apache exec user and document root permission

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

My Apache installation is launched by user `www-data` in group `www-data` by default.

For example, if I have this directory under the `/var/www/html`.

```
/var/www/html/myPhpProject
```

This directory owner is `whitebear`.

But a PHP framwork works on the server, sometimes it makes files owned by `www-data`, for example: `log` or `cache`.

Then there occurs some problems when user `whitebear` tries to update the framework, like logs can't be deleted.

What is the best practice for this?

Should `myPhpProject` be owned by `www-data`?

Should the `whitebear` user have the privilege same as www-data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do it, is to :

- Set  /var/www/html/myPhpProject and it's sub content owned by www-data

  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/myPhpProject

  - Give your Vhost the correct permissions :

  chmod -R 755  /var/www/html/myPhpProject

  - Give to **whitebear** the ability to do administration tasks like maintaining logs etc ... by either **SUDO**  or **Group Privilege**

***Sudo***

- Change the shell of **www-data** from **/bin/false** to **/bin/sh** :

  chmod -s /bin/sh www-data
- Change your sudoers file so **white bear** can switch to the user account **www-data** when doing his administration tasks :

  visudo

  Then append the above to the file :

  whitebear ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD : su - www-data

***Group privilege***

- Add **www-data** as secondary group to **whitebear** :

  usermod -G www-data whitebear

Comment: THank you very much your clear explanation, I am still strugging though, its great help.